# Open XPage document inside a Frameset

Tags: xpages, frameset

Scenario,
A scheduled agent send the link of documents via email notifications to users about documents that require action from the user.

Upon clicking the link from the email, I would like the link to open the Xpage document inside a frameset.

I tried the following URL but to no avail.

http://www.mywebsite.com/mydb.nsf/myframe?Openframeset&Frame=ContentPH&Src=/mydb.nsf/Document.xsp?documentID=xxxxxxxx&action=readDocument

The frame where I want the document to open is ContentPH frame.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should encode the url that's going to display inside the frameset. You have the ? twice in your url and your browser will cut it off there.

Try this:

http://www.mywebsite.com/mydb.nsf/myframe?Openframeset&Frame=ContentPH&Src=/mydb.nsf%2fDocument.xsp%3fdocumentID%3dxxxxxxxx%26action%3dreadDocument